# Algorithm to find centroid of historical datapoints without storing historical data

Tags: clustering, algorithms, online-algorithms

Is there an online learning algorithm for clustering that doesn't require storing historical data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's even a historic algorithm, too.

Look up online computation of the mean.

MacQueen used this 1967 for online clustering. See page 283.

Comment: Could you explain how that could be exploited to perform "clustering" (and what kind of clustering it would be)?

Comment: See MacQueen, 1967.

Comment: The paper in question is avaialble [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bsmsp/1200512992). (You should have said it is a paper, reading the comment seems like you refer to a book.)